# QGIS spatial filtering expressions

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 3.4

I have a set of points and I am using the atlas tool to generate reports for each point.

I'm looking for a way to only create reports for points that intersect a polygon.

These polygons change all the time, so im looking for a more on the fly way to filter these points, rather than the traditional select and save as a new layer.

​

In the atlas tools I see there is a "filter with" option and it gives you the ability to write an expression.

How can I create an expression/function to do the filter.

Comment: Do you have only one polygon, or multiple polygons? Are the polygons all in one layer?

Answer (score 3):

To filter the atlas features based on intersection with a **single polygon**, use this expression in the atlas filter, with substitutions as explained below:

```
 intersects( $geometry, geometry(get_feature('polygon_layer','attribute','value')))
```

- substitute the name of your polygon layer for `'polygon_layer'`
- substitute the name of an attribute in your polygon layer for `'attribute'`
- substitute the value of that attribute for the appropriate polygon for `'value'`

---

To filter the atlas features based on intersection with **multiple polygons**, use this expression in the atlas filter, with substitutions as explained above:

```
intersects( $geometry , aggregate( 'polygon_layer', 'collect', $geometry))
```

Comment: is that on the layer in question, or in the atlas filter expression?

Comment: @DPSSpatial use the expressions in the atlas filter expression. Also, I fixed a mistake in the expressions, so if you tried them before and they didn't work, try them again. I replaced `@atlas_geometry` with `$geometry`.

Comment: thanks! I hadn't thought about using them in the atlas filter.